# How to fix armoire to bent wall and mask the gap behind it?

Tags: walls, horizontal

So I made an armoire and want to fix it to the wall. But the wall is in the old house and it is tilt a bit, not forming an angle of 90 degrees. So if I just fix armoire to the wall it will not be horizontal and I don't want that.

Is there some standard procedure how to approach this problem?

I was thinking of simply taking some old wood of appropriate thickness, put it behind the armoire in appropriate place and then fix the armoire through that wood to the wall. For some reason I was hoping there is some better way of doing it, is there?

In addition, this will leave a hole looking from the side of the armoire. I thought of putting some moulding to cover it up, any other ideas?

Comment: What is the biggest gap and is it at the top or bottom?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you add a picture of the problem to your post? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

Your plan is fine (and exactly what I'd do). Most furniture has a small gap behind it anyway, so it shouldn't look bad.

The only other alternatives that won't look odd would be to actually shape the cabinet to fit the wall--the side panels and top would need to extend back at an angle. Trying to conceal the gap with trim boards might just draw attention to the matter.

If you wanted to, you could wrap the entire back perimeter with coordinating trim in whatever manner suits the style of the piece.